# basic bootstrap implementation results in blank page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried implementing the basics for bootstrap into an xmb forum templare but all I get is a blank page.

Prior to bootstrap:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"$charset\"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">

<!-- $versionlong  -->
<!-- Build: $versionbuild -->
<!-- $versioncompany -->
<head>

$baseelement$canonical_link

<title>{$SETTINGS[\'bbname\']} $threadSubject - $versionlong</title>

$css

<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/header.js\"></script>

</head>
```

and after bootstrap code:

```
<!-- ?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"$charset\"? -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">

<!-- $versionlong  -->
<!-- Build: $versionbuild -->
<!-- $versioncompany -->
<head>

<!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset=\"$charset\">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

$baseelement$canonical_link

<title>{$SETTINGS[\'bbname\']} $threadSubject - $versionlong</title>

<!-- $css -->

<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"./js/header.js\"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
```

Any clues as to the issue[s] appreciated.

Comment: maybe is just me, and only trying to help.. but.. I don't see any body tags or even the closing html, can it be the problem? what is supposed to be shown is what is inside the body tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to paste the link like this, everywhere else you are escaping quotes but here.

```
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css\" integrity=\"sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\">
```

Also, meta tag needs to be changed to

```
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no\">
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks iamwtk! That got it going. Now just css issues I guess! http://xmbforum2.com/xmbphp/

Comment: Glad it worked, if it solved your problem please mark as an answer. If you will have some other issues with CSS please make new question for specific problem.